# Is it bad practice to use setTimeout on an onClick event for a button to limit rapid clicking?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a button that  gets disabled when a local useState hook is true and is enabled when it is false. My onClick event calls a handle click function and the first thing it does is set this hook to true if it is not already true. If it is true, it returns and exits the function. I have a notification that pops up when the function finishes taking the action it does. The issue I am having is that if the Submit button is spammed, the user can click it multiple times before the submitButtonDisabled updates from false to true and results in multiple requests of the submit to be taken before it is disabled. My solution so far is to use the setTimeout() method on the handleClick method so that the submitButtonDisabled state has time to update. This works, but my intuition is telling me this is bad practice.

I don't see a situation where the state would take longer to update however theoretically if it takes longer than the 750ms (or however long I set it) it will send multiple requests and I am back at square one. I'm willing to accept this as my solution as it is currently working, but if there is a better practice, I want to know and implement it. An example of abbreviated code is below.

```
const MyFunction= () => {
    const [submitButtonDisabled, setSubmitButtonDisabled] = useState(false);

    const handleClick = () => {
        if (submitButtonDisabled) {
            return;
        }
        setSubmitButtonDisabled(true);

        // do a bunch of stuff.....
        // setSubmitButtonDisabled(false) in the resolve or reject of the async call
    };

    return (        
        <div className="main-div">                                
            <button
                className="button"
                onClick={() => {
                    setSubmitButtonDisabled(true);
                    setTimeout(handleClick, 750);}}
            >{submitButtonDisabled ? "Saving..." : "Submit"}</button>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: No matter how fast I click I can't click twice, are you doing async stuff in `// do a bunch of stuff.....` and do `setSubmitButtonDisabled(false);` before the asynchronous stuff finishes?

Comment: I am and the calls those make are asynchronous and the method wont end up making multiple calls in that respect. The issue is that this function invokes a toast-like message to the user and that will fire off multiple messages that I want to prevent. The debouncing that was linked is what I am looking for.

Comment: @HMR My example is misleading. I am setting the submitButtonDisabled in the resolution of the async call. Ill fix that in my code

Comment: This is not the duplicate that it automatically referred to, you already protect the function with `submitButtonDisabled`. The code in your question does not show `toast-like message` and how you do that but the timeout is not needed, maybe the message is shown whatever the `submitButtonDisabled` is or setting it to true too early.

Comment: i don't see the use of the timeout here at all. it looks like you're just delaying your function by .75 seconds for no reason

Comment: @JamesCourcelle Inside handleClick function code will never see where `/ do a bunch of stuff.....` comment is. Did you notice that? Because if it pass the `if` block, it will be ended by `setSubmitButtonDisabled`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure why react would fail to re-render the component that quickly, or why users are clicking that quickly, but regardless of that there are better options than directly using timeout to ensure the function can only be called once. Here are a few examples:

1. Set disabled on your button when `submitButtonDisabled` is true

   ```
   <button className="button" onClick={handleClick} disabled={submitButtonDisabled}>
     {submitButtonDisabled ? 'Saving...' : 'Submit'}
   </button>
   ```
2. You can utilize closures to make sure that the handleClick can only be called once per render

   ```
     import React, { useRef, useState } from 'react';

     const MyFunction = () => {
       const [submitButtonDisabled, setSubmitButtonDisabled] = useState(false);
       let hasClickBeenCalledThisRender = false;
       const handleClick = () => {
         if (submitButtonDisabled||hasClickBeenCalledThisRender) {
           return;
         }
         hasClickBeenCalledThisRender = true;
         setSubmitButtonDisabled(true);

         // do a bunch of stuff.....
         // setSubmitButtonDisabled(false) in the resolve or reject of the async call
       };

       return (
         <div className="main-div">
           <button className="button" onClick={handleClick}>
             {submitButtonDisabled ? 'Saving...' : 'Submit'}
           </button>
         </div>
       );
     };
   ```
3. You can use a ref to make sure that there's a disable immediately:

   ```
   import React, { useRef, useState } from 'react';

   const MyFunction = () => {
     const [submitButtonDisabled, setSubmitButtonDisabled] = useState(false);
     const submitButtonDisabledRef = useRef(false);
     const handleClick = () => {
       if (submitButtonDisabledRef.current) {
         return;
       }
       submitButtonDisabledRef.current = true;
       setSubmitButtonDisabled(true);

       // do a bunch of stuff.....
       // setSubmitButtonDisabled(false) in the resolve or reject of the async call
       // submitButtonDisabledRef.current = false
     };

     return (
       <div className="main-div">
         <button className="button" onClick={handleClick}>
           {submitButtonDisabled ? 'Saving...' : 'Submit'}
         </button>
       </div>
     );
   };
   ```
4. You can use throttle (brought to you in this case by lodash) to make sure your function can only be called every x amount of time (per update to submitButtonDisabled). (I realize now that this should've been debounce rather than throttle)

   ```
   import React, { useRef, useState, useMemo } from 'react';
   import { throttle } from 'lodash';
   const MyFunction = () => {
     const [submitButtonDisabled, setSubmitButtonDisabled] = useState(false);
     const handleClick = useMemo(() => {
       return throttle(() => {
         if (submitButtonDisabled) {
           return;
         }
         setSubmitButtonDisabled(true);
       }, 75);
     }, [submitButtonDisabled]);

     return (
       <div className="main-div">
         <button className="button" onClick={handleClick}>
           {submitButtonDisabled ? 'Saving...' : 'Submit'}
         </button>
       </div>
     );
   };
   ```

You can also make the throttle/debounce idea much more reusable and much less hacky.

Here's an example of useDebounce and useThrottle as well as a more normal option of just using button disabled

```js
const {
  useRef,
  useState,
  useMemo,
  useEffect,
  useCallback
} = React;
const {debounce, throttle} = _;

const MyFunction = () => {
  const [submitButtonDisabled, setSubmitButtonDisabled] = useState(false);
  const [numHandleClickRuns, setNumHandleClickRuns] = useState(0);
  const [
    submitDebounceButtonDisabled,
    setSubmitDebounceButtonDisabled
  ] = useState(false);
  const [numHandleDebounceClickRuns, setNumHandleDebounceClickRuns] = useState(
    0
  );
  const [
    submitThrottleButtonDisabled,
    setSubmitThrottleButtonDisabled
  ] = useState(false);
  const [numHandleThrottleClickRuns, setNumHandleThrottleClickRuns] = useState(
    0
  );
  const handleClick = event => {
    setSubmitButtonDisabled(true);
    setNumHandleClickRuns(num => num + 1);
    // console.log('here')

    setTimeout(() => {
      // fake async call
      setSubmitButtonDisabled(false);
    }, 1000);
  };
  const handleDebounceClick = useDebounceFn(
    event => {
      setSubmitDebounceButtonDisabled(true);
      setNumHandleDebounceClickRuns(num => num + 1);
      // console.log('here')

      setTimeout(() => {
        // fake async call
        setSubmitDebounceButtonDisabled(false);
      }, 1000);
    },
    1000,
    { leading: true, trailing: false, maxWait: 1000 }
  );
  const handleThrottleClick = useThrottleFn(
    event => {
      setSubmitThrottleButtonDisabled(true);
      setNumHandleThrottleClickRuns(num => num + 1);
      // console.log('here')

      setTimeout(() => {
        // fake async call
        setSubmitThrottleButtonDisabled(false);
      }, 1000);
    },
    1000,
    { leading: true, trailing: false, maxWait: 1000 }
  );

  return (
    <div className="main-div">
      <div>
        normal
        <button
          className="button"
          disabled={submitButtonDisabled}
          onClick={handleClick}
        >
          {submitButtonDisabled ? "Saving..." : "Submit"}
        </button>
        {numHandleClickRuns}
      </div>
      <hr />
      <div>
        debounce
        <button className="button" onClick={handleDebounceClick}>
          {submitDebounceButtonDisabled ? "Saving..." : "Submit"}
        </button>
        {numHandleDebounceClickRuns}
      </div>
      <hr />
      <div>
        throttle
        <button className="button" onClick={handleThrottleClick}>
          {submitThrottleButtonDisabled ? "Saving..." : "Submit"}
        </button>
        {numHandleThrottleClickRuns}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

const useDebounceFn = (
  fn,
  ms,
  options = { leading: false, trailing: true, maxWait: undefined }
) => {
  const fnRef = useRef(fn);
  useEffect(() => {
    fnRef.current = fn;
  }, [fn]);
  const debouncedFn = useMemo(
    () =>
      debounce((...args) => fnRef.current(...args), ms, {
        leading: options.leading,
        trailing: options.trailing,
        maxWait: options.maxWait
      }),
    [ms, options.maxWait, options.leading, options.trailing]
  );
  return debouncedFn;
};
const useThrottleFn = (
  fn,
  ms,
  options = { leading: false, trailing: true }
) => {
  const fnRef = useRef(fn);
  const argsRef = useRef([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    fnRef.current = fn;
  }, [fn]);
  const throttledFn = useMemo(
    () =>
      throttle(() => fnRef.current(...argsRef.current), ms, {
        leading: options.leading,
        trailing: options.trailing
      }),
    [ms, options.leading, options.trailing]
  );
  return useCallback(
    (...args) => {
      // Have to check to see if it is an event (using duck typing currently)
      if (args.length && args[0] && typeof args[0].persist === "function") {
        args[0].persist();
      }
      argsRef.current = args;
      throttledFn();
    },
    [throttledFn]
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<MyFunction />,document.querySelector('#root'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.15/lodash.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.13.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.13.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"/>
```

Comment: I think using a ref is the cleanest way to go here. Throttling shouldn't work in this case because a new function gets bound every rerender. It would only work if your throttled function lived outside a component in a service

Comment: Throttle will work here because it's in a `useMemo` call, so the only time the function will update is when submitButtonDisabled updates (due to the dependency array), which is coincidentally when the button stops receiving input!

Comment: Ah, I see, although it does get rebound later. Still seems a lot hackier than the other methods.

Comment: Perhaps, I tend to like thinking about throttling/debouncing over setTimeouts when possible due to the myriad issues that can occur if you aren't careful with setTimeout.

Comment: @frodo2975 I've added less hacky versions of useDebounce and useThrottle, and the method of doing this that I overlooked for some reason (disabled prop).

Comment: Thank you for the thorough answer. This has taught me a lot.